# Как создать 2 callback_query_handler чтобы они работали параллельно? ( библиотека telebot)

Tags: python, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['игроки'])
def info(message):
    global info_message
    conn = sqlite3.connect('football_players.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT surname FROM players")
    player_list = cursor.fetchall()
    if not player_list:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Список игроков пуст')
        return
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    for player in player_list:
        item = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=player[0], callback_data=player[0])
        markup_inline.add(item)
    info_message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите игрока', reply_markup=markup_inline)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True) #(Поправить надо что-то здесь)
def info_answer(call):
    global info_message
    conn = sqlite3.connect('football_players.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    surname = call.data
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM players WHERE surname=?', (surname,))
    player = cursor.fetchone()
    bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, player[11])
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,f'Фамилия:{player[1]}\nИмя: {player[2]}\nНомер: {player[3]}\nПозиция: {player[4]}\nГолы: {player[5]}\nМатчи: {player[6]}\nГолевые пасы: {player[7]}\nГ+П: {player[8]}\nЖелтые карточки: {player[9]}\nКрасные карточки: {player[10]}')
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, info_message.message_id)
    bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)




@bot.message_handler(commands=['матчи'])
def test(message):
    global match_message
    conn = sqlite3.connect('football_players.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT name, place FROM matches")
    match_list = cursor.fetchall()
    if not match_list:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Список матчей пуст')
        return
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    for match in match_list:
        item = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = f'{match[0]} {match[1]}', callback_data=f'{match}')
        markup_inline.add(item)
    match_message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите матч', reply_markup=markup_inline)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda  call:True) #(И тут)
def match_answer(call):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('football_players.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    temp = list(map(str, call.data[2:-2].split("', '")))
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM matches WHERE name=? AND place=?", (temp[0], temp[1]))
    match = cursor.fetchone()
    bot.reply_to(call.message, f"Соперник: {match[1]}\nСчет: {match[2]}\nРезультат: {match[3]}\nМесто проведения: {match[4]}")
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, match_message.message_id)
    bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
```